# Best way to import custom packages

Tags: python

I use `python` for data analysis. A lot of `pandas`. I have started writing modules to perform things I run often, like processing a file in a specific way.

To handle that, I created a folder named "packages", then I import the package like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/packages')
import importlib
import mypackage
importlib.reload(mypackage)
```

It's a bit of a hassle because I need to add the path (not the end of the world). I just keep the code block and copy and paste.

Is there a better way to handle custom local packages?

Answer (score 1):

I use `python -m pip install -e path/to/local/package`, preferably within a project-specific virtual environment. The package is set up in a pypi-compliant way (although not uploaded to pypi) with `setup.py` etc.

The `-e` option is "editable" and means any changes I make in the local package will be included in my client project, or at least as soon as I reimport it. (When working in interactive mode, `import importlib; importlib.reload("mypackage")` is invoked often.)